# Bootstrap 3 - dropdown search results under text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a text input in a navigation bar within bootstrap 3 framework.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <div class="navbar-form navbar-right">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." id="search" class="form-control" />
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle for that: http://jsfiddle.net/KKm3M/1/

What my text input does is hit the database for search results on keypress. It works fine, I tested it throwing results to a temporary div elsewhere.

Now I'd like to have these results show up in a drop down menu under the text input. The drop down should show up as soon as first results are returned from the backend. Tried searching for snippets but failed miserably. How can I do this?

Comment: What you are looking for is autocomplete I think. Check out [http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/](http://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/), a Twitter jQuery library for autocomplete

Comment: Thanks but I'm still far from home. Just including typehead.js completely messes my input field and makes it unresponsive to $("#search") selector. Perhaps someone could help me with a snippet?

Comment: Try read the documentation first, on [GitHub](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js). It's explain how to get started. If you still find yourself in trouble, please, post a new comment.

Comment: Tried yesterday and trying today and nothing...

Comment: You can use jquery ul http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote autocomplete right.

Comment: Update your question with your new code. What have you tried to do?

Answer (score 33):

You could use datalists:

```
<label for="something">
    Input "Something": 
    <input id="something" list="somethingelse">
    <datalist id="somethingelse">
        <option value="Something"></option>
        <option value="Something Else"></option>
        <option value="Another One"></option>
        <option value="Alpha"></option>
        <option value="Bravo"></option>
        <option value="Charlie"></option>
        <option value="Delta"></option>
        <option value="Echo"></option>
        <option value="Foxtrot"></option>
        <option value="Gamma"></option>
    </datalist>
</label>
```

The browser support is growing ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=datalist)).

[Here](https://codepen.io/alexander-holman/pen/QNQrvz) is an example of their use.

Comment: Even though this was nothing I needed or even was looking for; I love how you've made it without the use of JS at all. +1 for you my friend.